# Why are the Control.Handle value negative on Vista 64?

Tags: c#, handle

I was having a problem involving some negative Control.Handle value on a Vista 64 environment.

So I made a simple form to try it out.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = this.Handle.ToString();
        textBox2.Text = textBox2.Handle.ToString();
    }
}
```

I have tried both 86 and 64 version of this program, but on both the handles I would get look like these: -265484586, -266008916, -266205244....

If I run the programs on Win7, the handles would be normal. What's wrong? Am I wrong to assume the handles would always be positive?

Comment: Is it Vista SP2? From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle.aspx) is it only supported there and not below SP2 I assume.

Comment: umm, .Net 3.0 is in below SP2

Comment: ah! Oops. I misread the docs.

Comment: How do you end up with a problem with such values? Your application should be treating handles as opaque magic values.

Comment: Yes, you are wrong to assume handles should always be positive values.  It is an IntPtr, not an UIntPtr.

Comment: but I have to pass the handle to Delphi and HWND = type UINT_PTR, THandle = NativeUInt in Delphi so......